# Adding RadioButtons dynamically into a DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, radio-button

I'm trying to insert a new column into a `DataTable`, and then to insert a RadioButton for each row in the table.

I added a new column:

```
datasource.Columns.Add("RadioButtons");
```

After that, I tried to add a RadioButton foreach row in this table:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in datasource.Rows)
{
   dr[4] = new RadioButton();                        
   (dr[4] as RadioButton).GroupName = "Room1";
   Wizard1.ActiveStep.Controls.Add((Control)dr[4]);                        
}
```

And I get an error where I'm setting the GroupName:

> *Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You Can Try Generic List of RadioButton
Because No Column Has DataType RadioButton

Like

```
 List<RadioButton> List1 = New List<RadioButton>
```